# Fetching objects with Collections

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm trying to list objects that have an inner Collection. I can save and retrieve objects just fine, but when I do:

`parentRepo.findAll()`

Only the last object has it's child object listed, others has an empty collection.

**Parent model**

`@ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
 private Collection<Child> childs;`

**Child model**

`@DatabaseField(foreign=true,foreignAutoRefresh=true)
 private Parent parent;`

eager **true** or **false** doesn't make any difference. If i query a child and get its parent, I can get it's children as well. What am I missing?

Edit:

It's working for the modeling that I made. My mistake was that I need a Many-to-many relation between parent and child. I made a quick research and what I need is an intermediate model to achieve this. I'll close this question and will try to made this many-to-many relation between my models.

Comment: I just realize that I need a many-to-many relationship, not an many-to-one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve my Many-to-Many relationships like this: 
This is an example from an ongoing project. I have a Many-to-Many relationship between Preparation and GlideWax. To solve it I use thee classes: Preparation, GlideWax and PreparationGlideWax. PreparationGlideWax represents the connections between the the other classes, just like the way you usually solve many-to-many relationships with a table that is a "link" between the tables in the relationship. As you can see GripWax and Structure also has a Many-to_many relationship to preparation. Here is the code:

GlideWax.java

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "glide_waxes")
public class GlideWax {

    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private int id;

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false)
    private String name;

    @DatabaseField
    private String description;

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false)
    private int inUse;

    @DatabaseField(foreign=true)
    private WaxBrand waxBrand;

    @DatabaseField(foreign=true)
    private GlideWaxType glideWaxType;

    @ForeignCollectionField
    private ForeignCollection<PreparationGlideWax> preparationGlideWaxes;

    @ForeignCollectionField
    private ForeignCollection<TestSessionGlideWax> testSessionGlideWaxes;

    public GlideWax() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getInUse() {
        return inUse;
    }

    public void setInUse(int inUse) {
        this.inUse = inUse;
    }

    public WaxBrand getWaxBrand() {
        return waxBrand;
    }

    public void setWaxBrand(WaxBrand waxBrand) {
        this.waxBrand = waxBrand;
    }

    public GlideWaxType getGlideWaxType() {
        return glideWaxType;
    }

    public void setGlideWaxType(GlideWaxType glideWaxType) {
        this.glideWaxType = glideWaxType;
    }

    public ForeignCollection<PreparationGlideWax> getPreparationGlideWaxes()   {
      return preparationGlideWaxes;
    }

    public void setPreparationGlideWaxes(ForeignCollection<PreparationGlideWax> preparationGlideWaxes) {
        this.preparationGlideWaxes = preparationGlideWaxes;
    }

    public ForeignCollection<TestSessionGlideWax> getTestSessionGlideWaxes() {
        return testSessionGlideWaxes;
    }

    public void setTestSessionGlideWaxes(ForeignCollection<TestSessionGlideWax> testSessionGlideWaxes) {
        this.testSessionGlideWaxes = testSessionGlideWaxes;
    }
```

}

Preparation.java

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "preparations")
public class Preparation {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId=true)
    private int id;

    @ForeignCollectionField
    private ForeignCollection<PreparationGlideWax> preparationGlideWaxes;

    @ForeignCollectionField
    private ForeignCollection<PreparationGripWax> preparationGripWaxes;

    @ForeignCollectionField
    private ForeignCollection<PreparationStructure> preparationStructures;

    @DatabaseField(foreign=true, canBeNull = false)
    private SkiPair skiPair;

    @DatabaseField(foreign=true, canBeNull = false)
    private SkiTester skiTester;

    @DatabaseField(foreign=true)
    private Rfid rfid;

    @DatabaseField(foreign=true, canBeNull = false)
    private TestSession testSession;

    @ForeignCollectionField
    private ForeignCollection<Measurement> measurements;

    public Preparation() {
    }

    public int getId() {
       return id;
    }

   public void setId(int id) {
       this.id = id;
    }

    public ForeignCollection<PreparationGlideWax> getPreparationGlideWaxes() {
        return preparationGlideWaxes;
    }

    public void setPreparationGlideWaxes(ForeignCollection<PreparationGlideWax> preparationGlideWaxes) {
        this.preparationGlideWaxes = preparationGlideWaxes;
    }

    public ForeignCollection<PreparationGripWax> getPreparationGripWaxes() {
        return preparationGripWaxes;
    }

    public void setPreparationGripWaxes(ForeignCollection<PreparationGripWax> preparationGripWaxes) {
        this.preparationGripWaxes = preparationGripWaxes;
    }

    public ForeignCollection<PreparationStructure> getPreparationStructures() {
        return preparationStructures;
    }

    public void setPreparationStructures(ForeignCollection<PreparationStructure> preparationStructures) {
        this.preparationStructures = preparationStructures;
    }

    public SkiPair getSkiPair() {
        return skiPair;
    }

    public void setSkiPair(SkiPair skiPair) {
        this.skiPair = skiPair;
    }

    public SkiTester getSkiTester() {
        return skiTester;
    }

    public void setSkiTester(SkiTester skiTester) {
        this.skiTester = skiTester;
    }

    public Rfid getRfid() {
        return rfid;
    }

    public void setRfid(Rfid rfid) {
        this.rfid = rfid;
    }

    public TestSession getTestSession() {
        return testSession;
    }

    public void setTestSession(TestSession testSession) {
        this.testSession = testSession;
    }
```

}

PreparationGlideWax.java

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "preparation_glide_wax")
public class PreparationGlideWax {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId=true)
    private int id;

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false)
    private int layer;

    @DatabaseField(foreign=true, canBeNull = false)
    private GlideWax glideWax;

    @DatabaseField(foreign=true, canBeNull = false)
    private Preparation preparation;

    public PreparationGlideWax() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getLayer() {
        return layer;
    }

    public void setLayer(int layer) {
        this.layer = layer;
    }

    public GlideWax getGlideWax() {
        return glideWax;
    }

    public void setGlideWax(GlideWax glideWax) {
        this.glideWax = glideWax;
    }

    public Preparation getPreparation() {
        return preparation;
    }

    public void setPreparation(Preparation preparation) {
        this.preparation = preparation;
    }
```

}

Comment: I solved my problem exactly that way. I will accept your answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the edit, I'm able to load the child from parent just fine. My problem is that I need a many-to-many relation between my models. I'll accept this answer in two days.